# MS-Word VBA: How to make non printable characters as a caption in label?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to make the carriage return as the caption to my label by it doesn't display anything. My code is `Label1.Caption = Chr(13)`.

Comment: Why do you want to display a CR as a label?

Comment: It's just for labeling.

Comment: Labeling? as in printing to a label printer? It's not a displayable character, well not in a label. It will be created and any text after will be displayed on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out how to do it. Instead of using `Chr(13)`, I used `Chr(182)` `Label1.Caption = Chr(182)`